# API's to interpret Spring SimpleJDBCCall execute method

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring JDBC to interact with database procedures from my application. I am using SimpleJdbcCall to execute the procedure.

```
Map<String, Object> spResponse = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in); //in -> MapSqlParameterSource
```

My application consumes multiple database stored procedures. I am looking to have an reusable implementation/API to interpret jdbc execute call and have access to input parameters and the resulting output map. This will help me to log the input/output parameters, log execution time, handle exceptions, cache response etc.

Currently I am able to achieve this using Spring AOP Around aspect. But I want this listening to happen through an plug-in implementation(additional jar) outside the application and no(or very minimal) code changes within my application as it is a production ready version.

Any suggestions on the features/mechanisms to be applied will be very helpful.

Thanks.